# Trying to install Adobe Flash on fresh Ubuntu 16.10 instance

Tags: flash, adobe

I'm trying to install Adobe Flash Player on Ubuntu 16.10 and I'm having issues. I keep reading to use `apt-get install adobe-flashplugin` but that doesn't work for me like it does every other person. Any idea why?

```
alt@kl:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You need to add `Canonical Partners` repository in Software & Updates.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to install it successfully, but now sites such as Spotify still tells me that I need to install Flash. I checked chrome://plugins and it's indeed checked off. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner`
 to the end of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

After updating apt with `sudo apt update`, you can then do `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`.

Note: this also works for 17.10